# How to convert the length in pixel to the length in centimetre?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, opencv

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWXsS.png)
I want to find the length of this curved line and with the help of cv2.arclength() i found the total length of this curved line as u can see in the picture the "total_len 359.8477599620819" and i get to know that this is not in centimetres but this is in pixels so now i have to convert this pixel length to the real world measuring length like centimetres or millimetres and then i found a code [pixel to centimetre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bua2i.png) but after using this i found that it is showing 95.20971982330083 mm length which is wrong because the length should be between 25 to 30 mm. I don't know where did i made the mistake. I am using mac book air system and the picture resolution is 420 x 423 pixels. And i am also confuse how to use dpi and how to select dpi for this and if anyone have any other solution except the use of DPI then it will be a great help fo me.

I tried to convert the length but it is showing wrong length in millimetres as i already know the actual lengths i am expecting a conversion based on which  can convert it to pixel length to millimetre length measuring unit.

Comment: Do you know the original properties of the image? The magnification used etc. Pixel length in no way reflect the real world properties, such as length. @PMF answer addresses aspects that are required for on screen lengths.

Comment: The easiest way is probably to put an object, like a ruler, of known dimensions, in the image when imaging and scale off that. The object should be parallel to your imaging sensor and the same distance from the camera as the thing you wish to measure.

Comment: how did you even take that picture?

Answer (score 0):

There's no fixed conversion factor between pixels and cm, since the size of a pixel depends on the display used. A standard display is assumed to have a DPI (pixels per inch) of 96. This is approximately true for many computer monitors, but fails completely on large screens, smartphone displays or when using a projector. And when you print the image, the size is yet different again.

It is usually possible to get the DPI value of the used display with some function call, but that's still only an assumption.

Bottom line: That's not reliably possible, except for a very specific use case.

Comment: doesn't even depend on the display but on *how the picture was taken* because that seems to be what OP cares about.

Comment: What does the display have to do with anything?

Comment: This is a diagram, so I'm assuming the data is from some kind of simulation. I agree the answer would be very different if you'd ask "how big is the person in this pic?", but that's another level of complexity.

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution ?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PIL import Image
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
screen = app.screens()[0]
dpi = screen.physicalDotsPerInch()
app.quit()
im = Image.open("sky.png")
width, height = im.size
width_length = round(width / dpi)
hight_length = round(height / dpi)
print(width_length, hight_length)
```

I'm using `PyQt5` to get the screen's DPI and then deducing the size in inches of an image. You could adapt this to get the size in cm.

Hope this helps!

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, the screen's DPI setting is an estimate, that can typically even be changed by the user.

Comment: thx bro it worked..i am beginner at this sort of stuff..